# Log who make changes in iptables?

Tags: linux, logging, firewall, iptables, netfilter

We have some linux serves where we have iptables rules.Since there are a lot of people who can acces the server and change the iptables rules,I wanted to know if there is a way to log the changes made at iptables.
We use ssh access to the server.

Comment: The best answer begins with "limit the number of people who have permission to even run iptables". But you're asking on the wrong site, try http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score -1):

I'd do

```
alias iptables='echo "iptables $@" | logger && iptables $@'
```

or smth like this...